# average of exp of linear function

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, average, gaussian-integral

How to prove that $<e^{iA}>=e^{-<A^2>/2}$ ?, where average is taken w.r.t. a gaussian distribution (of any number of variables, let two (x,y)) and A is a linear function (without constant term, i.e, for two variables it will be lin combination of x and y)?
I tried to expand out exp in LHS in terms of cousin and sine then sine terms will vanish but cosine will remain and that will not be equal to the term that we'll get by expanding out RHS!
I got LHS= $1-\dfrac{<A^2>}{2!}+\dfrac{<A^4>}{4!}-\dfrac{<A^6>}{3!}+\ldots$ , and RHS=$1-\dfrac{<A^2>/2}{1!}+\dfrac{(<A^2>/2)^2}{2!}-\dfrac{(<A^2>/2)^3}{3!}+\ldots$, which, at least manifestally, doesn't seems to be equal!

Comment: Are you sure it won't be equal? You should put what you got for the LHS and RHS.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions)  may help (it's the MGF).

Comment: @Golden_Ratio LHS seems to be MGF indeed but how RHS is same thing I don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume yours is the case with mean zero.  First let's recall that for $s\in \mathbb{R},$ the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Examples) of a univariate normal random variable, $Y\sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma^2_Y)$, is $$E[\exp\left\{isY\right\}]=\exp\left\{is\mu_Y-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2_Ys^2\right\}.$$

In the multivariate case, for $X:=(X_1,...X_n)'\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$, note that for $t\in\mathbb{R}^n,$

$$A:=t'X\sim N(t'\mu,t'\Sigma t),$$

and applying the univariate characteristic function above (taking $s=1,Y=A$) tells us

$$E[\exp\left\{iA\right\}]=\exp\left\{it'\mu-\frac{1}{2}t'\Sigma t \right\}.$$

Now, in the case where $\mu=0$, then $E[A^2]=\text{Var}(A)=t'\Sigma t,$ so we can equivalently write

$$E[\exp\left\{iA\right\}]=\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}E[A^2] \right\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(a+bx)}e^{-x^2} \,dx=  e^{ia-b^2/4}$$

$$\displaystyle \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (a+bx)^2 e^{-x^2} \,dx\right\}= e^{-a^2/2-b^2/4}$$

Not equal.

### UPDATE

With $a=0$ they are equal.

In two dimensions:

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \, \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\alpha x +\beta y)}e^{-x^2} e^{-y^2} \,dx\, dy=  e^{-(\alpha^2/4 + \beta^2/4)}$$

$$\displaystyle \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2 {\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \, \int_{-\infty}^\infty (\alpha x + \beta y)^2 e^{-x^2} e^{-y^2} \,dx \, dy \right\}= e^{-(\alpha^2/4+\beta^2/4)}$$

Yes, they are equal.  You can easily extend this to more than two dimensions.

Note:  We've made use of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x e^{-x^2} \, dx=0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty xy\, e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \, dx\, dy=0.$

Comment: Sorry, I have edited question: there are no constant terms i.e, a=0, and this identity is true in any dimension. For 1D its trivial but I can not prove it in general.

Comment: Well, if $a=0$ then they are equal.

Comment: yes, in 1D. But how do I show it for any general case.....

Comment: What is your linear function in $n$ dimensions (or even in two dimensions)?  Is it:  $A= \alpha x + \beta y$ ?

Comment: A=$a_1 x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+\ldots$